# Slice away first element in each (list) element in a list in Python

Tags: python, list, numpy, slice

Say we have a list:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Then I want to create a new list through slicing away the first element in each element in the list:

```
b = a[][1:]
```

Obviously the above doesn't work, but what I want b to be now is:

```
[[2, 3], [5, 6], [8, 9]]
```

Of course I can just loop through it, but all I want to know is if it's possible to do it in any similar way of what I tried so wrongly to do above. Also, preferably is there a better/good way of doing this with numpy, in which case it doesn't need to be done through slicing the way I attempted to do it?

Comment: It's not a good idea to convert between python lists and numpy arrays all over the place - it takes quite a lot of CPU. You should try to minimise those conversions.

Comment: Do you mean slicing a numpy array is not a good idea if I already got everything in a numpy array?

Comment: No, I mean if for example you were converting from a list to a numpy array just to do the slice and then converting back to a list. Using a list comprehension would probably be faster because even though the numpy slice is very fast, the conversions back and forth are very slow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using numpy indexing/slicing notation, you use commas to delimit the slice for each dimension:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3]])
print a[:,1:]
```

output:

```
[[2 3]
 [2 3]
 [2 3]]
```

For additional reading on numpy indexing:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html

Comment: You are both right, and list comprehensions is a good idea, but I specifically specified I preferred a good numpy way of doing this, and you did it exactly the way I wanted it, so I have to set this as the accepted answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

You can use [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
b = [x[1:] for x in a]
```

Demo:

```
>>> a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> b = [x[1:] for x in a]
>>> b
[[2, 3], [5, 6], [8, 9]]
>>>
```

Comment: You are right, and I kinda knew about this, but wanted to do it without list comprehensions and loops etc, I also specified I preferred a numpy solution. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 2):

in python 3 you can also use *

```
b = [x for _,*x in a]
```

this approach is more flexible since you can for example left first and last elements of the inside list, no matter how long is the list:

```
b = [first,last for first,*middle,last in a]
```